# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() for image processing

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have the following code:

```py
import cv2

import math

import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread("/home/lenovo/Desktop/road/1.jpg")

img1=cv2.resize(img,(28,28))

print(img1.shape)

img2=img1[int(0.2*img1.shape[0]):-1]

img_gauss=cv2.GaussianBlur(img2, (49,49),sigmaX=2,sigmaY=2)

img_median=cv2.medianBlur(img_gauss,31)

img_diff=img_gauss-img_median+127

img_thres=img_diff

for i in range(img_thres.shape[0]):

    for j in range(img_thres.shape[1]):

        if(img_thres[i,j]>150):

            img_thres[i,j]=255

        else:

            img_thres[i,j]=0

kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)

erosion = cv2.erode(img_diff,kernel,iterations = 2)

dil = cv2.dilate(erosion,kernel,iterations = 2)

cv2.imshow("image",dil)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

My error is:

```py
if(img_thres[i,j]>150):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are loading in a colour image but the input is expected to be grayscale. When doing `img_thresh[i,j]` for a colour image, this will return a three-element array that corresponds to the RGB colour values at location `(i, j)` thus producing that error.  You can first solve the problem by ensuring that the image is loaded in as grayscale:

```
img=cv2.imread("/home/lenovo/Desktop/road/1.jpg", 0)
```

In addition, you can replace the double `for` loops with vectorized operations.  Instead you can do:

```
img_thres = 255*((img_diff > 150).astype(np.uint8))
```

Once you do the above two changes your code should work.